# Java function not returning expected output

Tags: java

I have this function below its intended purpose is to return the first index where data isn't sorted in ascending order. If the data is sorted, it will just return the length of the array. For example {10, 20, 90, 5, 70} would return 3 (90 > 5). If any of the data is null or invalid it just returns -1. Currently, the function is expecting 4 to be returned but it skips over the loops and returns -1 instead of 4. Any tips to help would be appreciated.

```
    public static int Sorted(int[] data) {
    if (data == null)
        return -1;
    for (int i = 0; i < data.length - 1; i++) {
        if (data[i + 1] < data[i])
            return (i + 1);
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Test cases:

```
public void testSorted() {
    assertEquals(-1, Stage1.partSorted(null));
    assertEquals(1, Stage1.partSorted(new int[] { 90, 20, 40, 100 }));
    assertEquals(4, Stage1.partSorted(new int[] { 10, 20, 40, 100 }));
    assertEquals(3, Stage1.partSorted(new int[] { 10, 20, 90, 70 }));
    assertEquals(4, Stage1.partSorted(new int[] { 20, 20, 30, 40, 5, 70, 90, 80 }));
}
```

Comment: If the list is already sorted `data[i+1] < data[i]` will never be true.

Comment: What is the desired return value when the array is sorted?

Answer (score 3):

You are testing a sorted array. For loop finishes itself and the `return` within it is never called. Last `return` before end of the function should be `return data.length;`

```
public static int partSorted(int[] data) {
    if (data == null)
        return -1;
    for (int i = 0; i < data.length - 1; i++) {
        if (data[i + 1] < data[i])
            return (i + 1);
    }
    return data.length;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code has some flaws. if you want to return the array length if the array is sorted in ascending order then you need to fix your last return statement.

The fixed code should look like this:

```
public static int Sorted(int[] data) {
    if (data == null)
        return -1;
    for (int i = 0; i < data.length - 1; i++) {
        if (data[i + 1] < data[i])
            return (i + 1);
    }
    return data.length;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The reason is, for a sorted array, you pass the for loop without returning a value, then, you return -1 with your last statement. Therefore, just **change `return -1` to `return data.length` in your last statement**,

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    public static int Sorted(int[] data) {
    if (data == null)
        return -1;
    int parSorCount = 1;
    for (int i = 1; i < data.length; i++) {
        if (data[i - 1] <= data[i]) {
            parSorCount++;
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }
    if (parSorCount < 2) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return parSorCount;
    }
}
```